# How and where to download JDK 6u201

Tags: java

Where can I download **java JDK 6u201**?

I tried from [oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html) but they don't have that version.

[image: scrennshot]

Comment: Try with https://sdkman.io/

Comment: Just as an additional input: *don't use "old" java versions*. Oracle will provide more minor updates in the future. So upgrading is the best way to go

Comment: @Lino actually it won't, even Oracle gave up on further milking Java 6 users with end of 2018

Comment: @KarolDowbecki sorry that came out wrong, I meant to say that oracle will provide smaller *major* updates, like java 11, java 12 and so on... In the future. So upgrading to a newer version will finally be better, because upgrading *then* will not be a big difference

Answer (score 5):

Oracle JDK 6u201 is a paid update from Oracle as part of extended support for JDK 6. You must purchase Oracle extended support to get this update, it's not publicly available.

Please note that as per [JDK 10.0.2, 8u181, 7u191, and 6u201 Released!](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/jdk-1002,-8u181,-7u191,-and-6u201-released) that's the last update to Oracle JDK 6:

> There is only 1 more update release scheduled for JDK 6 (October of 2018). JDK 6 will reach the end of extended support in December 2018. Applications running on JDK 6 that will remain in operation after December 2018 should be migrated to a newer JDK version as soon as possible.